# Best way to implement Interface between Activities and SDK [Android]

Tags: java, android

I am going to have following structure of the layers in an android application. Communication with SDK from Interface layer, in some cases it is blocking and in some cases it is non-blocking. SDK works in Request-Response basis, each request has corresponding response.

```
+------------+  +-----------+   +-----------+
| Activity 1 |  |Activity 2 |   |Activity 3 |
+------------+  +-----------+   +-----------+
       |              |              |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                Interface                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                  SDK                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

In above layers, interface is the medium which provides interface to communicate with the SDK API from various Activities.

### **Have below questions:**

1. How can Interface be implemented, by which it can be accessible from
   all the activities, and called from any of the activity to call SDK
   API, and also it provides response to calling activity only
   (Synchronous or Asynchronous).
2. How can Interface be kept alive and on going when application is not
   active or in background (Service not proffered), so that it can get notification from SDK.
3. How can Interface broadcast notifications received from SDK to
   all the available activities (is Broadcast Receiver mechanism ok for
   this?)?

What is the best practice to implement this functionality?

I have thought of having Interface as Singleton Class Providing functions for calling SDK APIs, but what about APIs that are Asynchronous and which takes time to execute?

Comment: 1. AIDL, Service
2. Why not Service? Content Providers maybe...
3. Intents

Answer (score 1):

> How can Interface be implemented, by which it can be accessible from
>   all the activities, and called from any of the activity to call SDK
>   API...

The interface instance can be made a context singleton (lazily instantiated). So you may have a `static getInstance(Context)` to get an implementation of the interface.

OR you can be using a Dependency injection framework (Roboguice, Dagger etc) and just annotate the class with `@Singleton`etc. This is useful if you would like to switch implementations of same interface dynamically.

OR you can extend `Application` class with your own `App` class, mention the same in manifest's `<application>` tag. Now `App` class will become app wide singleton and can one-time initialize and expose global objects from its `onCreate()` method.

> .., and also it provides response to calling activity only
>   (Synchronous or Asynchronous).

I'd advise to stick with single a pattern. Also UI components like Activities, Fragments and View are exposed to a risk of being frequently destroyed and re-created. So, It is a great responsibility of notifying the SDK to not to call back for a UI that is going away.

```
RequestHandle handle = mySDK.doSomeAsyncReqyest(myInputParameters, new Callback<Data>(){
   @Override
   public void onResult(Data d, Exception e){
      // handle results
   }
});
```

And always track the requests and remember to :

```
handle.cancel();
```

> How can Interface be kept alive and on going when application is not
>   active or in background (Service not proffered), so that it can get
>   notification from SDK.

As of now, a "sticky" Service equipped with a boot receiver is the only way you can let android not permanently destroy a background process of an app. Even then, the process will still be stopped if resources are low, and re-started when resources are free.

This service can post notifications in status bar (by becoming a foreground service), from where, user can again be re-directed to a specific part of your app.

> How can Interface broadcast notifications received from SDK to all the
>   available activities (is Broadcast Receiver mechanism ok for this?)?

Android offers `LocalBroadcastManager` to broadcast events local to the app. Also there are "bus" implementations such as `EventBus` and `Otto` that can help send events from one object to another without them having direct references of each other.

If you are looking for overall async architecture hints, you can explore how the framework called `RoboSpice` is implemented.